# undefined method `map' for :id:Symbol

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, undefined

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `map' for :id:Symbol):
    1: <div id="dropdown-no-2">
    2:    <%= collection_select 'challenge_id', challenges, :id, :full_challenge, include_blank: true %>.
    3: </div>
```

How can I solve this error so that only the challenges for that respective user are listed?

**duels/_dueler_fields.html.erb**

```
<%= f.select :user_id, User.order(:name).map { |user| [user.full_name, user.id] }, include_blank: true, id: "change-challenge-options" %>

  will

<%= render :partial => 'user_challenges', locals: {challenges: Challenge.order(:created_at)} %>

<script>
$( "#change-challenge-options" ).change(function() {
     $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: '<%= user_challenges_path %>',
        data: {name: $('#change-challenge-options').prop('value')}
     });
});
</script>
```

**duels/_user_challenges.html.erb**

```
<div id="dropdown-no-2">
   <%= collection_select(':challenge_id', challenges, :id, :full_challenge, include_blank: true) %>.
</div>
```

**duels/user_challenges.html.erb**

```
$("#dropdown-no-2").html('<%=j render :partial => "user_challenges", locals: {challenges: @challenges} %>');
```

**duels_controller.rb**

```
  def user_challenges
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @challenges = @user.challenges.order(:created_at)
  end

  def new
    @duel = Duel.new
    @duel.duelers << Dueler.new(user_id: current_user.id, user_name: current_user.name, user_last_name: current_user.last_name)
    respond_with(@duel)
   end
```

**routes.rb**

```
get 'duels/user_challenges', :to => 'duels#user_challenges', as: 'user_challenges'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this to:

```
<%= collection_select(:duel, :challenge_id, challenges, :id, :full_challenge, include_blank: true) %>
```

Refer [`collection_select`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_select)

Comment: Thank you! I changed `:duel` to `:dueler` because `:dueler` has the column `challenge_id`. This removed the error, but I'm still struggling with my larger goal over at this question if you're willing to assist: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39349262/how-to-only-show-dropdown-options-for-user/39350351#39350351 :)

Answer (score 0):

Third parameter of `collection_select` has to be a collection (to populate the select), not a symbol.

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_select